# Create script to update table row based on division of two selects from 4 related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables.

```
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| School               | Event        | SchoolStore  | Order     |
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| Id                   | Id           | SchoolId     | Id        |
| OrdersAverageNumber  | SchoolId     |              | EventId   |
|                      | IsDeleted    |              | Status    |
|                      | Status       |              | Date      |
|                      | Date         |              |           |
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

**relation picture**
https://ibb.co/gwJ8QkM

My goal is to insert ordersAverageNumber in each School

value must be

(Total Amount of all Orders with Status = 1 and for the period startDate - endDate)

divided by

(Total Amount of all Events with Status = 1 and IsDeleted = 0 for the period startDate  - endDate)

I tried to select data according to provided criteria but it is very hard to me to combine everything together.

Here i tried to make division of two selects

```sql
select ((select count(*) 
        from [Order]
        where(OrderStatus = 1 AND CreatedDate >= @startDate AND CreatedDate <= @endDate))
        /
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM [Event]
        WHERE ("IsDeleted" = 0 AND "Status" = 1 AND "Date" >= @startDate AND "Date" <= @endDate)))
```

Here i tried to query related table data

```sql
select distinct s.OrdersAverageNumber, evn.Id, evn.Status, evn.Date, evn.IsDeleted, ord.Id, ord.CreatedDate, ord.OrderStatus
from [School] s
join [SchoolStore] ss on s.Id = ss.SchoolId
join [Event] evn on evn.SchoolId = ss.SchoolId
join [Order] ord on ord.EventId = evn.Id
where(evn.IsDeleted = 0 
  AND evn.Status = 1
   AND evn.Date >= @startDate 
  AND evn.Date <= @endDate 
  AND ord.OrderStatus = 1 
  AND ord.CreatedDate >= @startDate 
  AND ord.CreatedDate <= @endDate)
order by ord.CreatedDate desc
```

Main problem for me is to imagine how to run this query for all schools, divide this two selects from related tables.

Comment: Which column belongs to order amount?

Comment: I updated my post with table relations image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join `event` and `order` to `school` then group by the school and get the distinct counts of event and order IDs. If for a school there is no event or order, the count will be 0 as `count()` doesn't count `NULL`s. To avoid division by zero errors use a `CASE` expression that only divides when the count of events isn't `NULL`.

```
SELECT s.id,
       CASE
         WHEN count(DISTINCT e.id) <> 0 THEN
           count(DISTINCT o.id) / count(DISTINCT e.id)
       END ordersaveragenumber
       FROM school s
            LEFT JOIN event e
                      ON e.schoolid = s.id
                         AND e.isdeleted = 0
                         AND e.status = 1
                         AND e.date >= @startDate
                         AND e.date <= @endDate
            LEFT JOIN order o
                      ON o.eventid = e.id
                         AND o.orderstatus = 1
                         AND o.createddate >= @startDate
                         AND o.createddate <= @endDate
       GROUP BY s.id;
```

Comment: I need to left join SchoolStore to the School?

Comment: @I.Nikos: Why? You don't seem to need any data from it, unless I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Seems that it returns correct Orders Average Number, but is it possible to insert this value in School tables OrdersAverageNumber  column?

Comment: @I.Nikos; You could but you shouldn't because that bears a severe risk of inconsistent data. Drop the `OrdersAverageNumber` column and create a view with the query instead. The view will then always give you accurate figures.

Comment: Hmm, view is something like a virtual table and it will only display that data but i want to update existing `orders average numbers` column in `School` table with values from selection above.